# First app - Random.nextInt() unresolved reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin, random

I have followed this tutorial for building an android app. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOfCEhWq8sg

It goes well up until the end, where we generate a random val using `Random.nextInt()`. In Android Studio (3.3), I get an error :

> an unresolved reference to nextInt.

I have made sure I am using the right spelling. This program uses Kotlin, and I even imported `java.util.*` to get the Random library imported.

Please help me out, it is very discouraging not being able to get such a simple application built.

Thanks.

Comment: post your code what you have tried.

Comment: I can just guess here: Did you really write `Random.nextInt()`? `nextInt` is not a static method. It needs to be called on an instance of class `Random`.

Comment: "I even imported java.util.* to get the Random library imported." That's the problem, the video likely uses `kotlin.random.Random` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use `Random` class from `java.util` package you need to create an instance of `Random` class. Instances in Kotlin are created using **NameOfClass()** syntax:

```
java.util.Random().nextInt()
```

If you use `Random` class from `kotlin.random` package you don't need to create an instance of the class:

```
kotlin.random.Random.nextInt()
```